# Hangindent and page breaks

Tags: formatting, page-breaking

I like using `\hangindent` in my math documents to properly and nicely separate paragraphs and emphasize the first line, which usually contains the title of the theorem of definition.

However, I've noticed that the use of `\hangindent` disables the Tex functionality to vertically fill pages before a page break by stretching paragraphs in the page.

In other words, using `\hangindent` makes the `\pagebreak` command act as the `\newpage` command, stopping the page as is and not stretching its contents to fill it.

Example : the end of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAbtj.jpg) page is ended by `\pagebreak` and yet there is space left at the end of it.

Does anyone know of a solution or of an alternative to hangindent that does not cause such an issue ? Thx

Here's the code of the linked document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\parindent 0pt
\parskip 1em

\newcommand\norme[2]{\Vert#1\Vert_{#2}}
\def\K{\mathbb{K}}\def\N{\mathbb{N}}\def\R{\mathbb{R}}\def\C{\mathbb{C}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \huge{\textbf{Séries entières}}
\end{center}
Soit $E$ un espace vectoriel normé complet. Soit $\K=\C$ ou $\K=\R$

\section{Notion de série entière}
\subsection{Définition}

\hangindent .5cm \textbf{Définition.} Soit $(a_n)$ une suite de $E$. On appelle série entière associée à la suite $(a_n)$ la série de fonctions de $\K$ dans $E$ : $\sum a_nz^n$
\par

\hangindent .5cm\textbf{Lemme.}
Soient $\sum a_nz^n$ une série entière à coefficients dans $E$ et $z_0\in\K^*$ tel que la suite $(a_nz_0^n)$ soit bornée.\\
Alors la série $\sum a_nz_0^n$ converge absolument et pour tout $z\in\K$ tel que $|z|<|z_0|$. La série entière converge même normalement dans tout disque fermé $D'(0,r)=\left\{z\in\K/|z|\leqslant r\right\}$ pour tout $r<|z_0|$
\par

\hangindent .5cm \textit{Démonstration :}
Soient $M\geqslant 0$ tel que  $\forall n\in\N,\norme{a_nz_0^n}{}\leqslant M$ et $x\in\K$ tel que $|z|<|z_0|$. On a alors $\norme{a_nz^n}{}\leqslant\norme{a_nz_0^n}{}\left| \dfrac{z}{z_0} \right|^n\leqslant M \left| \dfrac{z}{z_0} \right|^n$.
Comme $\left| \dfrac{z}{z_0} \right|<1$, la série géométrique converge donc $\sum a_nz^n$ converge absolument.
Pour $z\in D'(0,r)$, on a de même $\norme{a_nz^n}{}\leqslant M \left| \dfrac{r}{z_0} \right|^n$ qui est indépendante de $z$ et de série convergente. Donc la série converge normalement sur $D'(0,r)$.
\par

\hangindent .5cm \textbf{Théorème.}
Soit $\sum a_nz^n$ une série entière à coefficients dans $E$. On pose $R_1=\sup\left\{|z|/\,\sum a_nz^n\text{ converge}\right\}\in\R\cup\left\{+\infty\right\}$ et $R_2=\sup\left\{|z|/\,(a_nz^n)\text{ bornée}\right\}$\\
On a alors $R_1=R_2$ et en notant $R$ cette valeur commune, la série converge absolument dans le disque ouvert $D(0,R)=\left\{z\in\K/|z|<R\right\}$ et converge normalement sur tout disque fermé $D'(0,r)=\left\{z\in\K/|z|\leqslant r\right\}$ où $r<R$
\par

\hangindent .5cm \textit{Démonstration :}
Soit $r\in[r,R_1[$. Il existe $z\in\K$ tel que $\sum a_nz^n$ converge avec $r<|z|\leqslant R_1$ par définition de la borne supérieure. Alors, $\lim a_nz^n=0$ donc la suite $(a_nz^n)$ est bornée donc $(a_nr^n)$ l'est aussi. Ainsi, $r\in[0,R_2]$ donc $[0,R_1]\subset[0,R_2]$ donc $R)1\leqslant R_2$.
Soit $r\in[0,R_2[$. Il existe $zin\K$ tel que $(a_nz^n)$ soit bornée avec $r<|z|\leqslant R_2$ par déinition de la borne supérieure. Par lemme d'Abel, $\sum a_nr^n$ converge absolument. Donc, de même, $R_2\leqslant R_1$. Donc $R_1=R_2$\\
Soit alors $z\in D(0,R)$. Il existe $z_0\in\K$ tel que la suite $(a_nz_0^n)$ soit borée et $|z|<|z_0|\leqslant R$. Par lemme d'Abel, $\sum a_nz^n$ converge absolument. De même, pour $r<R$, il existe $z_0\in\K$ tel que $(a_nz_0^n)$ soit bornée avec $r<|z_0|\leqslant R$. Par lemme d'Abel, $\sum a_nz^n$ converge normalement sur $D'(0,r)$
\par

\hangindent .5cm \textbf{Définition.}
$R$ est appelé rayon de convergence de la série entière, $D(0,R)$ son disque ouvert de convergence et $C(0,R)$ donc cercle de convergence
\par

\subsection{Recherche du rayon de convergence}
\hangindent .5cm \textbf{Théorème} (Règle de d'Alembert) :
On suppose que $\forall n\in\N,a_n\neq 0$. Si la suite $\dfrac{\norme{a_{n+1}}{}}{\norme{a_n}{}}$ admet une limite $\ell\in\R^+\cup\left\{+\infty\right\}$, alors le rayon de convergence de la série entière $\sum a_nz^n$ est $\dfrac{1}{\ell}$

\hangindent .5cm \textit{Démonstration :}
Il suffit d'appliquer la règle de d'Alembert pour les séries numériques en remarquant que $\dfrac{\norme{a_{n+1}}{}z^{n+1}}{\norme{a_n}{}z^n}$ est $\ell|z|$

\pagebreak

\subsection{Opérations sur les séries entières}
\hangindent .5cm \textbf{Proposition.}
Soient $\sum a_nz^n$ et $\sum b_nz^n$ deux séries entières à coefficients dans $E$ de rayons de convergence respectifs $R_1$ et $R_2$ et $\alpha,\beta$ des scalaires.\\
Alors la série $\sum(\alpha a_n+\beta b_n)z^n$ a un rayon de convergence supérieur ou égal à $\min(R_1,R_2)$ et $\forall z\in\K/|z|\leqslant\min(R_1,R_2),\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}(\alpha a_n+\beta b_n)z^n=\alpha \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nz^n+\beta \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}b_nz^n$
\par

\hangindent .5cm \textit{Démonstration :}
En effet, si $|z|<\min(R_1,R_2)$, les deux séries $\sum a_nz^n$ et $\sum b_nz^n$ convergent\linebreak donc $\sum(\alpha a_n+\beta b_n)z^n$ converge aussi.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Show the code (I never used hangindent for this purpose and have not idea what you are actually doing).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added the code. There might be a few personal commands in there that therefore won't work. Use of `\hangindent` [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Paragraph_indent) or [here](https://texblog.org/2013/02/27/on-paragraphs-in-texlatex/).

Comment: Well then remove or define the personal commands. A document that gives lots of errors is not suitable for a test.

Comment: Probably you are interested in using a theorem-derived environment for the lemmas, definitions and propositions.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: IIRC, the default \parskip has glue in it.  Try \addtolength{\parskip}{1em}.